# Where can i get started making an instant messenger in xamarian.forms and MQTTnet

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Anyone know any open source instant messengers in xamarian.forms using MQTTnet
because im new to MQTTnet and need an example which i cant seem to find

EDIT:
Why am i getting down votes im just asking for a place to start

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try signalR or Firebase realtime db.
For the start, watch a video by James Montemagno.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CqoLGnOPSA

Also check out the official docs for signalR on xamarin forms.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-signalr.

Comment: Thanks i will take a look :)